# Zurb Foundation _global.scss meta styles for js?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, meta

I was working on a Foundation 5 project that turned out to have an outdated _global.scss component. I was trying to get [range sliders](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/range_slider.html) working, but they were mysteriously not. Turns out, I was missing the following 2 lines of CSS:

```
meta.foundation-data-attribute-namespace {
  font-family: false;
}
```

Can someone explain these lines to me? The Docs say this:

```
// Used to provide media query values for javascript components.
// Forward slash placed around everything to convince PhantomJS to read the value.

meta.foundation-mq-small {
  font-family: "/" + unquote($small-up) + "/";
  width: lower-bound($small-range);
}

meta.foundation-mq-medium {
  font-family: "/" + unquote($medium-up) + "/";
  width: lower-bound($medium-range);
}

meta.foundation-mq-large {
  font-family: "/" + unquote($large-up) + "/";
  width: lower-bound($large-range);
}

meta.foundation-mq-xlarge {
  font-family: "/" + unquote($xlarge-up) + "/";
  width: lower-bound($xlarge-range);
}

meta.foundation-mq-xxlarge {
  font-family: "/" + unquote($xxlarge-up) + "/";
  width: lower-bound($xxlarge-range);
}

meta.foundation-data-attribute-namespace {
  font-family: #{$namespace};
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of Foundation's JavaScript needs to know about the different media query ranges definitions.

It is particularly true for some components such as interchange that is literally about things behaving differently depending on the viewport.

But foundation also [lets you customize](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html#customize-with-sass) what the different breakpoints are.

In order to make have the value set in one single place, foundation uses this little trick of adding the media query breakpoint definition of a meta with a matching class name.

Here's how it works, for the breakpoint `$small-up` (it's the same for the others):

Let's say you keep the default value: `$small-up: only screen`.

The JS in foundation will do the following:

1. create a `<meta>` tag with the class `.foundation-mq-small`
2. read the value of the CSS property `font-family`
3. now it knows what is the definition of the `$small-up` media query
4. it's now accessible to the different foundation js components that may need it

You can see how it's done in [foundation.js](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/c10052e7ab667aaf8085f830e0e91e490097474b/js/foundation/foundation.js#L281-L287)

The reason why it's using `font-family` is that it's one of the rare CSS properties that doesn't have a defined set of values. If they had used the property `text-align`, the browser would have ignored the invalid value and the JS would have gotten something like `left` in return.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. That last bit about font-family serving as a placeholder, because it can't have an invalid value was the key I was missing in my comprehension.

Comment: As far as I can think, the `content` also allows any value, but only applies to `:before` and `:after`, which you can not access in JS